# How do I decompose a vector into $2$ orthogonal vectors where all coordinates are integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, integers, cross-product

I have a vector $\mathbf{n}=\langle a,b,c \rangle$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers and $\mathbf{n}\ne\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$.

I want to find two other vectors $\mathbf{v_a}$, $\mathbf{v_b}$ that are in $R^3$ with integer coordinates such that $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{v_a} \times \mathbf{v_b}$.

For example, when $\mathbf{n}=\langle3,5,7\rangle$, a solution is $\mathbf{v_a}=\langle-1,2,-1\rangle$ and $\mathbf{v_b}=\langle-3,-1,2\rangle$.

I wrote a brute force solution that works on all vectors $\mathbf{n}$ where $a,b,c\in [-15,15]$ (a 31 x 31 x 31 cube centered around the origin). Based on this test, I'm reasonably confident there is a solution for every valid $\mathbf{n}$. However I'm not sure my brute force solution will work for all $a,b,c$ and the brute force solution is slow.

Is there a simple way to find $\mathbf{v_a}$ and $\mathbf{v_b}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference added: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103152/determinant-of-integer-lattice-basis-of-l-x-1-ldots-x-n-a-1x-1-cdotsa

**Yes, there is**. Write your target vector as a row $R$ of fixed integers. **We require their gcd to be 1**. Now, using a sequence of **column** operations using elementary matrices $C_j,$ each of all integers and each determinant $1.$ The resulting process must transform $R$ into $(1,0,0).$ Furthermore, there will actually be few $C_i,$ with the product $C_1 C_2 C_3 ... = C.$ Then we have
$$ RC = (1,0,0).   $$

Given this notation, the two desired vectors are the second and third column of $C.$ If we call those columns $v,w,$ then either $v \times w = R^T$ or $w \times v = R^T$

Let me make some examples...

$$ 
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 5 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ 
C =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-2& 10& -7 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1&-5&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
As rows, we have the solution vectors
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
10& 1& -5 \\
-7 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Finding $C$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? r = [ 3,5,7]
%1 = [3, 5, 7]
? c1 = [ 1,0,-2;0,1,0; 0,0,1]
%2 = 
[1 0 -2]

[0 1  0]

[0 0  1]

? r * c1
%3 = [3, 5, 1]


? c2 = [ 1,0,0;0,1,0; -3,-5,1]
%6 = 
[ 1  0 0]

[ 0  1 0]

[-3 -5 1]

? r * c1 * c2
%7 = [0, 0, 1]

? c3 = [ 0,0,-1;0,1,0; 1,0,0]
%11 = 
[0 0 -1]

[0 1  0]

[1 0  0]

? matdet(c3)
%12 = 1
? r * c1 * c2 * c3
%13 = [1, 0, 0]
? c = c1 * c2 * c3
%14 = 
[-2 10 -7]

[ 0  1  0]

[ 1 -5  3]

? r * c
%15 = [1, 0, 0]
? matdet(c)
%16 = 1
?
```

P.S. If $g = \gcd(a,b,c) > 1,$ solve the problem for $\left(\frac{a}{g}, \frac{b}{g}, \frac{c}{g} \right).$ After finding $v,w,$ **multiply one of them by $g$ but not the other.**

============================================================================

$$ 
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
6 & 10 & 15
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ 
C =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1& -10& -15 \\
1 & -9 & -15 \\
-1&10&16 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
As rows, we have the solution vectors
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-10& -9& 10 \\
-15 & -15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? r = [ 6,10,15]
%1 = [6, 10, 15]
? c1 = [ 1,0,0; 1,1,0; -1,0,1]
%2 = 
[ 1 0 0]

[ 1 1 0]

[-1 0 1]

? matdet(c1)
%3 = 1
? r * c1
%4 = [1, 10, 15]
? c2= [ 1,-10,-15; 0,1,0; 0,0,1]
%5 = 
[1 -10 -15]

[0   1   0]

[0   0   1]

? r * c1 * c2
%6 = [1, 0, 0]
? c = c1 * c2
%7 = 
[ 1 -10 -15]

[ 1  -9 -15]

[-1  10  16]

? matdet(c)
%8 = 1
?
```

===============================================================

Added: we could also write the thing out in symbols, given $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1,$ with $g = \gcd(b,c) $ and Bezout expressions $sb+tc= g$ and $pa+qg=1.$ Then the method given leads us to general solution
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-g& sa& ta \\
0 & -\frac{c}{g} & \frac{b}{g} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

With the example
$$ 
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 5 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we get $a=3, b=5, c=7, g=1, s=3,t=-2,q=1   $ and 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1& 9& -6 \\
0 & -7 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In this dimension we can use Gauss reduction to find a reduced basis,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& 1 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1& 9& -6 \\
0 & -7 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1& 2& -1 \\
-3 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think I understand your answer and I have a question about the last section of your answer:

Is there an algorithm for doing the Gauss reduction to find a reduced basis or did you choose the reduction to match the example I gave in my question?

Comment: @doodleoodle There is a fast algorithm for reducing positive binary quadratic forms. It is due to Gauss. It can be found in many places, books or notes on number theory. If one is careful, the steps can be written using elementary (2 by 2) matrices of integers; the product is a matrix of determinant one. As I was writing the basis in two rows, in the end I used the transpose matrix as shown. For problems with more vectors and higher dimension, look up LLL basis reduction.

Comment: @doodleoodle I think there is a way you can learn reduction quickly. Continue writing the basis as two rows, $v$ in the top row and $v$ in the lower. As I wrote the $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& 1 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) ,$ alternatively multiply by $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& 0 \\
w & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ to minimize $|u \cdot v|,$ then if $|v| >|u|$ multiply by $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0& 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ Done properly, this is very easy (by hand) and very fast. Result: $|u| \leq |v|$ and $2 |u \cdot v| \leq |u|$

Comment: @doodleoodle the $w$ in the matrix above is an integer. Oh, I described the reduction algorithm in a certain way, it is a theorem that this forces $|u|$ to be the smallest possible vector length in a basis.